# Issue with height:auto for content with variable height? (jsFiddle)

Tags: html, css

For the following HTML, I would like the container to wrap the section+content+element(s), and I would like element2 to be a direct (float:left?) continuation of element1..

```
<div class="page">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="section">
        <div class="content">
          <div class="element1">Elements Goes Here And Here And Here And Here .. more elements hereafter</div>
        </div>
      </div>        
        <div class="section">
        <div class="content">
          <div class="element1">Elements Goes Here And Here And Here And Here</div>
          <div class="element2">more elements hereafter</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This CSS isn't working though http://jsfiddle.net/sLnY5/3/:

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 74px;
    height: auto;
  border: 1px solid rgba(142, 142, 142, 1);
}
.section {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 37px;
    height: auto;
  border: 1px solid rgba(142, 142, 142, 1);
        background-color: blue;
}
.content {
    float: left;
    min-height: 37px;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 1.42;
    padding: 2%;
  border: 1px solid rgba(142, 142, 142, 1);
}
.element1 {
    float: left;
    font-size: 12.9px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    letter-spacing: 0.07em;
    background-color: green;
}
.element2 {
    float: left;
    padding-left: 3px;
    background-color: purple;
}
.page {
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 5%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of a scenario where you would want to use `float: left;` with `width: 100%;`.  In my experience, `float` is overused and largely misunderstood.  I'm not sure what you mean by "a direct continuation of element1", but it sounds like you might want `display: inline;`.

[jsfiddle.net/sLnY5/4](http://jsfiddle.net/sLnY5/4/)

Comment: Any chance you could take a look at this..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24496037/css-child2-variablewidth-based-on-child1-variablewidth-parent-max-width-jsfi seems to be another overuse of float.. Regardless, much appreciated